# "translating" One character to another in lua

Tags: lua, hexchat

I want to make a lua script that takes the input of a table, then outputs the strings in that table in their full width counterparts, eg

```
input = {"Hello", " ", "World"}
print(full(table.concat(input)))
```

and it will print "Ｈｅｌｌｏ　Ｗｏｒｌｄ"

I tried it using this:

```
local encoding = [[　０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［\\］＾＿‘｛｜｝～]]
function char(i)
   return encoding:sub(i:len(),i:len())
end
function decode(t)
   for i=1,#t do t[i]=char(t[i]) end
   return table.concat(t)
end
function returns(word, word_eol)
    print(char(word_eol[2]))
end
```

but that did not work

note: it is a plugin for hexchat that's why I have it as `print(char(word_eol[2])))`

Because when you hook a command in hexchat it spits out a table that is the command name, then what was entered after

Comment: I don't even understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Piglet - It appears that unicode has a set of "fullwidth" ASCII characters starting at `U+FF00`. OP wants to convert any string to fullwidth, for example, to bypass a swear filter :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (string) = [[　０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［\］＾＿‘｛｜｝～]], you're finding the *n* th character of (string), with *n* being the length of the character, which will always be one. If I understand correctly, this will do the job, by having a separate alphabet and matching the characters.

```
local encoding = [[　０１２３４５６７８９ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ！゛＃＄％＆（）＊＋、ー。／：；〈＝〉？＠［］＾＿‘｛｜｝～]]
local decoding = [[ 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&()*+,-./:;{=}?@[]^_'{|}~]]
function char(i)
   local l = decoding:find(i,1,true)
   return encoding:sub(l,l)
end
function decode(t)
   for i=1,#t do t[i]=char(t[i]) end
   return table.concat(t)
end
function returns(word, word_eol)
    print(char(word_eol[2]))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function full(s)
   return (s:gsub('.', function(c)
      c = c:byte()
      if c == 0x20 then
         return string.char(0xE3, 0x80, 0x80)
      elseif c >= 0x21 and c <= 0x5F then
         return string.char(0xEF, 0xBC, c+0x60)
      elseif c >= 0x60 and c <= 0x7E then
         return string.char(0xEF, 0xBD, c+0x20)
      end
   end))
end
```

Comment: Here I come swear filters! (xD JK)